# Group product at different price

Tags: magento-1.9, grouped-products

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to group products into an indivisible new product. For example, group two apples, three bananas and one pear into a new fruit basket product.

I want to be able to set a price for the composite product which is not simply the sum of the prices of the items in the composite.

I don't wan the customer to be able to select the composite and then deselect some of the items. If they want a fruit basket, then they get three bananas, they can't just buy two.

I want to keep the benefits of stock management. So when a fruit basket is sold, the stock of apples is reduced by two, bananas by three and pears by one.

I've looked at grouped, configurable and bundled products but none seem to fit my needs. The nearest is grouped, but I can't set a different price and customer can deselect items from the group.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you. You'll need to create a bundle product.

1. Under `Price` tab, you can set the price for this product.
2. Under `Bundle Items` tab

   2.1 In `Shipment` category choose `Together`

   2.2 Under `Bundle Items` category press `Add New Option` button. Here, as 
   Input Type choose `Multiple Select`. Add your products and for each product set price to be 0. Also you can add qty for each product.

Now go into your `template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/multi.phtml` and add this script which will select all your products which belongs to the bundled product

```
<script>
jQuery('#bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?> option').prop('selected', true);
</script>
```

Also you will need to hide this multiselect from frontend using `display: none` under your css files. It is mandatory to hide it in order not to let the user choose which products to buy.

Good luck !